# React axios await dispatch in UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to wait for my axios action to dispatch before continuing in UseEffect

```
import { getBrief } from '../../store/actions/agency-brief'
import agencyBriefReducer from '../../store/reducers/agency-brief-reducer'

    const [agencyBrief, dispatch] = useReducer(agencyBriefReducer, [])
    
          useEffect(async () => {   
            await getBrief(briefId)(dispatch);
            console.log('BRIEF', agencyBrief)
          }, [])
```

So console log here is undefined, I need to wait before

action:

```
export const getBrief = (briefID) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        let res = await axiosInstance.get(`/agency_briefs/reactGetBrief/${briefID}`)
        console.log('sre', res )
        return dispatch({ 
            type: 'GET_BRIEF', 
            payload: res.data
        }) 
     }
     catch (err) {
         console.error(err);
     }
}
```

reducer:

```
const agencyBriefReducer = (state, {payload, type}) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'GET_BRIEF':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    brief: payload
                }   
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I've tried async / await but it doesn't work, I need to wait so I can use the result to set the state ? Thanks

Comment: why don't you use `useSelector` hook?

Comment: I'm using context api

Comment: try to add `agencyBrief` in your `useEffect` dependency array.

Comment: wouldn't that create an endless loop?

Comment: try to console your value outside `useEffect` and check.

Comment: but I'm curious that it's not a good approach to work with context API, have a look at https://www.sitepoint.com/replace-redux-react-hooks-context-api/

Comment: outside I get 2 console logs with nothing and a third that has the result, but instead on consolelog I want to set a state and I only want to set it once

Answer (score 0):

ok, so one of the comments suggested 2 useEffects and that does the trick:

```
useEffect(() => {   
    getBrief(briefId)(dispatch);
}, [])
 
useEffect(() => {   
  console.log('BRIEF', agencyBrief)
}, [agencyBrief.brief])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [agencyBrief, dispatch] = useReducer(agencyBriefReducer, [])
        
useEffect(async () => {   
  await getBrief(briefId)(dispatch);
  console.log('BRIEF', agencyBrief) // will always console []
}, [])
```

Start by explaining why the source code does not behave as expected. `useEffect(() => {}, [])` Since the dependency is an empty array, this method will only be executed once when the page is initialized. In this render, the value of `agencyBrief` is always `[]`, will not change.

If you want to monitor the change of the result after the await asynchronous request ends, you can do this:

```
const [agencyBrief, dispatch] = useReducer(agencyBriefReducer, [])
        
useEffect(async () => {   
  await getBrief(briefId)(dispatch);
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  // Now agencyBrief is the latest value after await async request ends
  console.log('BRIEF', agencyBrief)
}, [agencyBrief])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it, I hope that would help.

```js
import { getBrief } from '../../store/actions/agency-brief'
import agencyBriefReducer from '../../store/reducers/agency-brief-reducer'

const [agencyBrief, dispatch] = useReducer(agencyBriefReducer, []);

const getBrief = async () => {
  await getBrief(briefId)(dispatch);
}

useEffect(() => {   
  getBrief();
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  if (agencyBrief) {
    // perform action
  }
}, [agencyBrief]);
```

Answer (score -2):

This should resolve your issue .

```
import { getBrief } from '../../store/actions/agency-brief'
import agencyBriefReducer from '../../store/reducers/agency-brief-reducer'

    const [agencyBrief, dispatch] = useReducer(agencyBriefReducer, [])
    
          useEffect(async () => {   
            await getBrief(briefId)(dispatch);
            setTimeOut(()=>console.log('BRIEF', agencyBrief),10);
          }, [])
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code ?

Comment: too many async calls, which is not recommended, and `setTimeout` is not an option. When you're sure about the answer then should have posted the answer otherwise you can suggest and ask your queries in the comment section. thanks

Comment: `agencyBrief` will still resolve to the initial value (undefined) even after 10ms due to closure. And also, using `setTimeout` seems hacky for this situation. Instead, we can create another `useEffect` which has a dependency on `agencyBrief`.

Comment: Okay ! Got it . 
Should I delete this answer then ?